# Error: 404 The page you're looking for could not be found (gitlab). How to resolve it?

Tags: deployment, gitlab, vuejs3

Let's say I have some website with the name website.eu. When I deploy it and try to get access to a page online like this website.eu/about I catch the error:
"404 The page you're looking for could not be found. The resource that you are attempting to access does not exist or you don't have the necessary permissions to view it"

When I click on the link that brings me a website.eu/about it works well, but trying to type that URL in the input field it fails.

Everything works fine locally.
The project is developed using Vue3.
The project is no GitLab.

If someone helps I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the code, but my guess is your router setup uses the web history mode, which relies on the server to have certain settings applied.

I believe switching to [hash mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#hash-mode) (while adding `#` to the routes) will work.

Alternatively, you can update your server to support redirects to have the html mode work.

[example server configurations](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)